# ScrollView not playing nicely with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-relativelayout

So I have a ScrollView as the highest-level in my layout...within my ScrollView I have a RelativeLayout which contains other views. The problem is that the RelativeLayout does not cover the entire layout as it should, It cuts off at about half the screen. It's width is the full width of the screen, but the height of the RelativeLayout stops where the bottom of the ImageView is. here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@drawable/graybck">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pPicture"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pPicture"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pBio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pName"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/stats"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pName"
    android:layout_marginRight="266dp"
    android:text="Loading Stats..." />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use android:fillViewport="true" as scrollview param.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<Scrollview> 
    <LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout>
        inner part here ...
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>  
</Scrollview>
```

Try using something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Comment: You should add explanations of the differences between your post and original one. And also add why you made these changes.