# MarginBottom has no effect on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I want to have a marginTop & marginBottom on the RelativeLayout, but only the marginTop seem to work. MarginBottom has no effect at all. I'm using a 9-patch-png as background, but the bottom of the RelativeLayout looks cut off.

This is the structure in my app: **(old, not working)**

```
FrameLayout
  ScrollView
    RelativeLayout (layout_marginTop="**", layout_marginBottom="**")

      --Content/Views--

    /RelativeLayout
  /ScrollView
/Framelayout
```

**(New, working)**

```
FrameLayout
  ScrollView
    LinearLayout
      RelativeLayout (layout_marginTop="**", layout_marginBottom="**")

      --Content/Views--

      /RelativeLayout
    /LinearLayout
  /ScrollView
/Framelayout
```

Comment: ScrollView and RelativeLayout apparently match badly. See this question, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907794/

Comment: Alright, adding a LinearLayout fixed the problem, thank you!